# boost unsorted_hash user define type

Tags: c++, boost

There is a user define type as the key of the unsorted_map. I would like to know how to customize the hash function and test equality function.

Thanks.
Michael

Edit: By the way the key is character array.

Comment: Perhaps stupid question, but have you checked the *documentation*?

Comment: Put the equality operator into the class itself. For the hash function, best to specialise `std::hash`.

Comment: I try to google it before. However, I cannot find any userful doc. Can you point it out? Thanks.

Comment: thank you Kerrek. do you know any example so that I can take a look?

Comment: ¤ See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/unordered/hash_equality.html. Possibly your googling foo failed because you wrote "unsorted" rather than "unordered"? Attention to detail very important. :-) Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for is something like `boost::hash_combine`
It allows you to create a hash value out of multiple fundamental types.

- [Boost Hash Combine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html)